# When storing a datetime in sql server (datetime type), what format does it store it in?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

When storing a datetime value in sql server 2008, using the datetime type, what format will it store the value in?

Is it the number of seconds since 1970 (or whatever)?

On the application side (.net), I am passing in a datetime object.

When I view the table's rows in query analyzer, will it format it according to my culture settings or am I viewing exactly what is stored in the db?

Comment: Not an answer but a general tip.  Cast as binary will help diagnose curiosities like this and others(unicode).  select cast(getdate() as binary);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Internally, according to SQLDenis, **they are stored as two integers** 
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server

When you view them in the query analyzer you are seeing evaluated numbers.

It is **not** stored as "unix time" 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: +1 I've always wondered if they were floating point, what the exponent was used for, and if precision would decrease further into the future :)  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Correct, glad that post I wrote could help someone  :-)

Comment: @SQLMenace do you have a notification when SO referrals come in or did you just happen to read this question? :D

Comment: I happened to see it in the referers by chance :-)

Comment: @Matthew what do you mean I am seeing evaluated numbers?

Comment: @codecompleting I mean that, when queried, the DB engine & query analyzer is turning its base data-type (integers) into the displayed date you see.

Comment: @SQLMenace can I take the logical leap to think that the SQL2008 `DATE` type only uses a single int then?

Answer (score 7):

It's stored as a floating point representing days since January 1st, 1900.  If you round it down by casting it to an int, that leaves only the date part:

```
select  cast(cast(getdate() as int) as datetime)
-->
2011-07-12 00:00:00.000
```

Or if you add a number to it, that's adding a number of days.  For example, adding 0.5 is equivalent of adding 12 hours:

```
select  getdate() + 0.5
-->
2011-07-12 11:22:09.927
```

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) for details.

Datetime does not include format information; query analyzer can display it in any way it likes.  It will probably try to honor your client PC's regional settings.

Comment: +1 They may be treated as floating points and manipulated in SQL as if they were, but when they are written to disk they are ints.

Comment: They are stored as 2 ints, see my post here http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to view how it is stored:

```
DECLARE @now datetime, @bytenow binary(8)
SELECT @now = getdate()
SELECT @bytenow = convert(binary(8), @now)
SELECT @now AS fulldate, @bytenow AS internal,
       convert(int, substring(@bytenow, 1, 4)) AS days,
       convert(int, substring(@bytenow, 5, 8)) AS ticks
```

This shows the 2 values:

1. the first 4 bytes is a number representing days since 1-1-1900
2. the second 4 bytes is the number of ticks since midnight where one second has 300 ticks.

.

```
fulldate                internal           days        ticks
----------------------- ------------------ ----------- -----------
2016-11-07 10:54:13.080 0x0000A6B700B3AFB4 42679       11775924
```

Reference: [Solving the Datetime Mystery](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery) see *figure 3*

Comment: Why the downvote? I like to improve, but I need to know what part of this answer you feel is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime doj = new DateTime();

System.Globalization.CultureInfo c1=new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB",true);
doj = DateTime.Parse(Txtdoj.Text.Trim(), c1, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

use
..it

use query to display the date time
select convert (varchar(max),doj,103)as doj from tbl_registration