# How are the "money" and "decimal" data types in SQL Server stored in memory?

Tags: sql, sql-server, memory

I want to know about the storage SQL Server data types in memory.

How is the `money` data type in SQL Server stored in memory? I know that `money` is stored in 8 bytes and `smallmoney` is stored in 4 bytes. But I don't know how?

For example when you have 123400.93 for the money, how is it stored in 8 bytes?

I have the same question about the `decimal` and `DATE` data types.

Especially for `DATE`, the format is YYYY-MM-DD, but how is it stored in 3 bytes? Is it stored as described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html 
or the number of days from a specific day is stored?

Comment: It is **not** stored in a string (character) form. Please confirm that you know that.

Comment: Do you care about in memory storage and not in data files?

Comment: Yes! I know that it is not stored in char.

Comment: I am caring about the memory storage. what is exactly in 3 bytes storage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just adding a bit here...

A single `byte` is made up of 8 `bits`. A `bit` can hold 2 values (0 or 1).

So 4 bytes is 32 bits (4 x 8).  Which means the numeric range of what can be stored is from 0 to 2^32 which gives a total range of 4,294,967,296 values.

`smallmoney` is signed so we drop one of the bits to be used for the sign, which leaves 2^31, or 2,147,483,648 possible values and the +/- sign.

Now we take into account that the last 4 digits of a money type are always after the decimal point and we end up with a range of -214,748.3648 to 214,748.3647

Technically, money and smallmoney values are stored by flipping bits in a word or byte just like everything else.  If you need more info, read http://computer.howstuffworks.com/bytes.htm

Or you might see this for the possible value range of money and smallmoney: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx

**update**
For the `DATETIME` data type, it's the same concept with a little twist.  In MS SQL a `DATETIME` is stored using 2 numbers.  The first is number of days since 1/1/1900 and the second is number of ticks since midnight: 
See
http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server and [When storing a datetime in sql server (datetime type), what format does it store it in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656658/when-storing-a-datetime-in-sql-server-datetime-type-what-format-does-it-store)

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that I get it. What about the "DATE" ? do you know how is it stored?

Comment: For your update, you should be referring to `datetime`, not `date`. SQL Server has had a specific `date` data type since the 2008 release, and it certainly *doesn't* store a time component.

Answer (score 3):

> How are the "money" [...] data types in SQL Server stored in
>   memory?

If you want to see how is stored a MONEY (8 bytes) value then you could execute following script step/step:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestMoneyDT;
GO
USE TestMoneyDT;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyMoney -- :-)
(
    Col1 CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Col2 MONEY NOT NULL,
    Col3 CHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT dbo.MyMoney (Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES ('AAAAA',12345678.0009,'BBBBB');
GO

-- Install http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-sp_allocationmetadata-putting-undocumented-system-catalog-views-to-work/
EXEC sp_AllocationMetadata 'dbo.MyMoney'
GO
/*
Stored procedure output:

Object Name Index ID Alloc Unit ID     Alloc Unit Type First Page Root Page First IAM Page
----------- -------- ----------------- --------------- ---------- --------- --------------
MyMoney     0        72057594039697408 IN_ROW_DATA     (1:147)    (0:0)     (1:150)
*/

SELECT DB_ID() AS DBID
GO
/*
DBID
----
13
*/

-- Reading data from page (1:147) (file id 1, page number 147)
DBCC TRACEON(3604);         -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187329.aspx
DBCC PAGE(13, 1, 147, 3);   -- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/10/625659.aspx
DBCC TRACEOFF(3604);        -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174401.aspx
GO

-- See [Memory dump @0x0000000014AEA060] of DBCC PAGE output
/*
Memory Dump @0x000000000E76A060

0000000000000000:   10001600 41414141 41e9f698 be1c0000 †....AAAAAéö.¾... 
0000000000000010:   00424242 42420300 00†††††††††††††††††.BBBBB...  

41414141 41 = AAAAA <- Col1 CHAR(5)
e9f698 be1c0000     <- Col2 MONEY take this string and run following script (look at SumOverAll values)
424242 4242 = BBBBB <- Col3 CHAR(5)
*/
GO

DECLARE @HexString VARBINARY(8) = 0xE9F698BE1C; -- One MONEY value consumes 8 bytes
WITH N10
AS 
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)) x(Num)
)
SELECT  src.*, 
        SUM(src.IntValueMultipliedByte) OVER() AS SumOverAll
FROM
(
    SELECT  n.Num, 
            SUBSTRING(@HexString, n.Num, 2) AS HexValue,
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@HexString, n.Num, 1)) AS IntValue,
            POWER(CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0), 256), n.Num-1) AS Byte,
            CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@HexString, n.Num, 1)) * POWER(CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0), 256), n.Num-1) AS IntValueMultipliedByte
    FROM    N10 n
    WHERE   n.Num <= LEN(@HexString)
) src;
GO

/*
NumHexValue IntValue    Byte       IntValueMultipliedByte SumOverAll
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------------------- ------------
1  0xE9F6   233         1          233                    123456780009
2  0xF698   246         256        62976                  123456780009
3  0x98BE   152         65536      9961472                123456780009
4  0xBE1C   190         16777216   3187671040             123456780009
5  0x1C     28          4294967296 120259084288           123456780009
*/
```

Note: I used SQL2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find this interesting [Performance / Storage Comparisons : MONEY vs. DECIMAL](https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal)

> The person arguing for MONEY showed the space used by MONEY compared
> to the same information stored in a DECIMAL(20,4) column.  **Not all
> that surprisingly, the latter was slightly larger.**  But is that the
> whole story?  No, for two reasons.  One is that the *performance* of
> these choices was not compared, and the other is that DECIMAL(20,4) is
> not a very realistic requirement for storing currency data.  **Unless
> you are storing the pricing information for luxury yachts or aircraft
> carriers, in which case you can probably drop the decimal places
> altogether and use INT or BIGINT.**  For the rest of us, a better choice
> would be DECIMAL(8,2) or DECIMAL(10,2).

Also check this related question: [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not worried about the performance and storage space. I want to know that "How is it stored in memory?"

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think it would be stored in the similar way as Decimal values are stored.! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal :)