# Date multivalued attribute in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date

I am really confused about whether `Date` is a multivalued attribute or not.

Because it contains Date - month-year (22-10-1990). We are able to split this as 22 as day, 10 as month and 1990 as year. But when we specify date of birth we enter like 22/10/1990. So I can't understand whether `date` is a multivalued attribute or single valued attribute.

Comment: Please expand your question. It is unclear what you ask.

Comment: No, it's **not** multi-valued. Any `DATE` column can contain **EXACTLY ONE** Date at most. Multi-valued would mean that a single cell could store **multiple values** of the defined type, e.g. a single cell (row/column) could contain three or five dates - **that** would be multi-valued! (and it would also be against even the first normal form of database design)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate: [When storing a datetime in sql server (datetime type), what format does it store it in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656658/when-storing-a-datetime-in-sql-server-datetime-type-what-format-does-it-store)

Dates are internally stored as 2 integers. The first integer is the number of days before or after the base date (1900/01/01). The second integer stores the number of clock ticks after midnight, each tick is 1/300 of a second.