# Convert Datetime to Varchar exactly as is

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to convert a datetime, to a varchar exactly as is.

So I would like the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30),'2014-10-21 12:02:22.555')
```

To return exactly 2014-10-21 12:02:22.555 every time. I have researched this a bit, but I don't see a difference in the options in converting a full date to varchar like this. Will this work with all dates just using the basic convert(varchar(30), with no option at the end?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This sounds like it should be a concern for your presentation code rather than for SQL.

Comment: In your question, you are converting a string to `VARCHAR(30)`, which makes no sense (or rather, it does nothing). Do you mean to convert a string to `DATETIME`, or vice versa?

Comment: I am actually using it within the hashbytes function which does not support passing in a datetime so I need to convert it. 


SELECT HASHBYTES('md5',Datetime) fails

Comment: Aha, now that's an entirely different question. You may wish to edit it to make that clear. `HASHBYTES` does operate on binary data, so a simple `CONVERT(BINARY(8), datetime)` should do.

Comment: I'm doing multiple columns at once added together within a persisted computed column. That is why I was looking for the varchar value. The answer below is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Exactly as it is" isn't really correct - [something stored in the DATETIME format is actually stored as two integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6656706/1225845).  What you see when you select it is actually just those two integers, formatted in a certain way.  The advantage of this is that many applications can recognize a DATETIME data type and allow you to use functions and formats against it that you wouldn't be able to apply to a character field (e.g., DATENAME, DATEADD, etc.)

To convert it to varchar in the same default format that SQL Server Management Studio will display, you can use [format code 121](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx), like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(),121)
```

This will return *2014-10-21 13:24:31.353*, which is the same format that SSMS displays by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some test sql for all the styles. Make nvarchar(max) shorter to trim (e.g. nvarchar(10)) .

```
 DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETDATE()
    select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 0) as output, 0 as style 
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 1), 1
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 2), 2
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 3), 3
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 4), 4
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 5), 5
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 6), 6
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 7), 7
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 8), 8
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 9), 9
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 10), 10
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 11), 11
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 12), 12
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 13), 13
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 14), 14
    --15 to 19 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 20), 20
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 21), 21
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 22), 22
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 23), 23
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 24), 24
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 25), 25
    --26 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 100), 100
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 101), 101
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 102), 102
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 103), 103
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 104), 104
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 105), 105
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 106), 106
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 107), 107
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 108), 108
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 109), 109
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 110), 110
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 111), 111
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 112), 112
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 113), 113
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 114), 114
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 120), 120
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 121), 121
    --122 to 125 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 126), 126
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 127), 127
    --128, 129 not valid
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 130), 130
    union select convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 131), 131
    --132 not valid
    order BY style
```

Here's the result

```
output                   style
Apr 28 2014  9:31AM          0
04/28/14                     1
14.04.28                     2
28/04/14                     3
28.04.14                     4
28-04-14                     5
28 Apr 14                    6
Apr 28, 14                   7
09:31:28                     8
Apr 28 2014  9:31:28:580AM   9
04-28-14                     10
14/04/28                     11
140428                       12
28 Apr 2014 09:31:28:580     13
09:31:28:580                 14
2014-04-28 09:31:28          20
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      21
04/28/14  9:31:28 AM         22
2014-04-28                   23
09:31:28                     24
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      25
Apr 28 2014  9:31AM          100
04/28/2014                   101
2014.04.28                   102
28/04/2014                   103
28.04.2014                   104
28-04-2014                   105
28 Apr 2014                  106
Apr 28, 2014                 107
09:31:28                     108
Apr 28 2014  9:31:28:580AM   109
04-28-2014                   110
2014/04/28                   111
20140428                     112
28 Apr 2014 09:31:28:580     113
09:31:28:580                 114
2014-04-28 09:31:28          120
2014-04-28 09:31:28.580      121
2014-04-28T09:31:28.580      126
2014-04-28T09:31:28.580      127
28 جمادى الثانية 1435  9:31:28:580AM    130
28/06/1435  9:31:28:580AM    131
```

Refer page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385/how-to-convert-datetime-to-varchar)